# Popup location and size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a popup that appears when I click a button, and it stays for 10 seconds or till the user clicks elsewhere.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_popup_function(id) {
        var popup = document.getElementById(id);
        popup.classList.toggle("show");

        let timeout;

        function hide() {
            popup.classList.remove("show");
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hide);
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', hide)
        timeout = setTimeout(hide, 10000)
    }
</script>
```

The *[div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements)*:

```
<div id="loading-overlay" style="display: none;">
   <div id="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 600px; /* Increase the width to accommodate multiple lines */
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left; /* Align the text to the left */
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* Center the popup horizontally */
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The *[span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Div_and_span)* which has to be clicked to see the popup:

```
<div>
    <div
        class="popup"
        onclick="show_popup_function('C1686551567729')"

        >Click here to view and copy to the clipboard
        <span class="popuptext" id="C1686551567729"
        >NA</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The span text (which will be displayed in popup) comes from a DB with line breaks as `<br>`.

The text here is multiline and the length of each line is different. What is needed is that the width of the popup should be enough to accommodate the longest line.

The problem is that it shows up like this for small text:

[image]

The popup arrow is located in the center which makes enables the scrollbar:

[image]

It should show something like this:

[image]